# How can I fetch the WordPress cart errors normally displayed in woocommerce-error?

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm working on adding these errors to our AJAX fragments callback, but I'm not sure what filter I need to use to fetch them.

It's the errors reported by this template file: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/657c312caeef7345b225ffb899da6dbb84692936/templates/checkout/cart-errors.php

Shown in the HTML like so:

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error" role="alert">
        <li>You cannot add that amount of "product name" to the cart because there is not enough stock (4 remaining).</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to fetch this error and store it to a variable inside my theme's functions.php file, any suggestions greatly appreciated.